# Error Calling a VPC Resource into other Resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I deployed a VPC using a For loop in terraform

```
#All VPCs being deployed
resource "aws_vpc" "All_VPCs" {
  for_each = var.All_VPCs
  cidr_block = each.value.ip
  instance_tenancy = each.value.instance_tenancy

  tags = {
    Name = each.key
  }
}
```

This For loop referenced my Variable.tf file

```
#VPC CIDRs
variable "All_VPCs" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    Dev_VPC = {
      ip = "10.0.3.0/24"
      instance_tenancy = "default"
    }
    Transit_VPC = {
      ip = "10.0.4.0/23"
      instance_tenancy = "default"
      description = "Transit_VPC"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to call it inside an Internet gateway resource, but it failed.

```
#Transit Internet Gateway
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "Transit_Internet_Gateway" {
  vpc_id = var.All_VPCs.Transit_VPC

  tags = {
    Name = "Transit VPC Internet_Gateway"
  }
}
```

Here is the error message

```
vpc_id = var.All_VPCs.Transit_VPC
│     ├
│     │ var.All_VPCs.Transit_VPC is map of string with 3 elements
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "vpc_id": string required.

It makes me wonder. Do I need to specify an ID when calling a Variable?
Or do I need to call the VPC resource in some way inside the Internet gateway resource, instead of calling its variable?
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just realized I simply had to refer to the VPC resource, but also a string of the Tier one value. This value is "Transit_VPC." I must also reference the VPCs ID, as this is a Resource and not a Variable.

```
#Transit Internet Gateway
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "Transit_Internet_Gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.All_VPCs["Transit_VPC"].id

  tags = {
    Name = "Transit VPC Internet_Gateway"
  }
}
```